# reuse numerical value from a text entry in subsequent entries

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate a procedure and to create the output file that I need. So far everything is going well, but I cannot figure out how to take the number at the end of one row and fill it in for rows after it.

I've tried solutions using awk, sed, etc, but so far, I can't seem to figure this out even with the helps of many googles.

POP-Test-01
10.10.10.10
User: User
Pass: Pass

POP-Test-02
10.10.10.11
User: User
Pass: Pass

POP-Test-03
10.10.10.12
User: User
Pass: Pass

But I want it to take the numerical values from the first line, and append it to the user and pass lines. But for the pass line, I'd like to add it twice.

POP-Test-01
10.10.10.10
User: User01
Pass: Pass0101

POP-Test-02
10.10.10.11
User: User02
Pass: Pass0202

POP-Test-03
10.10.10.12
User: User03
Pass: Pass0303

These are only examples, but the last two digits of the hostname(ex. POP-Test-03) will always be numerical digits.

Edit:
I've had some requests for more details. Sorry about that guys, so here is the skinny. Please note that all values are fake, these come from an input file. I just used the most generic values I could think of.

The input is a text file with only the values in the top example. 
So I run a script that deploys instances and the only output I get from the deployment script is the Hostname and the IP address. I know it's not clean, but below is how I'm adding the user and password. But the user and pass are always the same between each batch of servers with only the number of the server being appended to the user and the password(twice). I'm doing this because an application we use requires the input of:
HOSTNAME
IP
User: (username)
Pass: (password)
(empty line)

Normally I have to enter these manually which is time consuming and I was hoping not necessary since I've started it with the commands below in a script I am trying to build to automate the process.

So I start with this: 
POP-Test-01
10.10.10.10

And I'm trying to get to this:
 
POP-Test-01
10.10.10.10
User: User01
Pass: Pass0101

```
awk '/([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}/{print;print "User\: 
Train";next}1' DeploymentDetails2.txt | tee DeploymentDetails2.txt<br/>

awk '/User/{print;print "Pass\: Training";next}1' 
DeploymentDetails2.txt | tee DeploymentDetails2.txt<br/>

awk '/Pass/{print;print "\n";next}1' DeploymentDetails2.txt | tee 
DeploymentDetails.txt<br/>
```

Comment: `A='POP-Test-03'; b=$(echo $A| cut -d'-' -f3); echo $b`

Comment: First tell us where you are getting, e.g. `POP-Test-03` and `10.10.10.12` from? Are these prior user inputs, filenames, file-contents, what? Are the `User: User` and `Pass: Pass` lines already present or are you adding them? If they are file-contents, the post the first 10 lines or so from the file they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to produce what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="POP-Test-"
IP=10
for i in {01..99} ; do
  echo ${HOST}${i}
  echo "10.0.10.${IP}"
  echo "User: User${i}"
  echo "Pass: Pass${i}${i}"
  echo
  let IP++
done
```

As you did not specify that there was an input file, I took the liberty of generating the ending number in the script, and reusing it in the user and pass lines.

Comment: Well, if it is generation question, that's the way to do it, (though I would use a `printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n" ...` for a single call and then `((IP++))` rather than `let`)

Comment: Sorry, this does come form an input file and those were just example IPs, they are actually random and my input file has the first section, and I just want to finish it off so that our other script can input the values properly.